# Limit visibility to Google Domain Shared Contacts

Tags: google-api, google-contacts-api, google-provisioning-api, google-shared-contacts

Is it possible to limit the visibility of google domain shared contacts?

Assuming that my organization structure has: A report to B reports to C.

If A adds a new shared contact is visible for everyone.

If B adds a new shared contact is visible for C but not(or with limitations) for A.

Maybe combining this with Google Provisioning API?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

google domain shared contacts are available for domain administrator only.

Answer (score 0):

Shared Contacts and User profiles that are not hidden are made part of the Global Address List that is accessible to all accounts in the domain. It is not possible to limit access to the GAL except by turning it off for all users under Settings -> Contacts in the CPanel.

Additionally, non-admins do not have rights to modify the Shared Contacts for the domain. There are however third party applications in the Google Apps Marketplace that allow end users to add/remove contacts from the Shared Contacts.